# AsyncTaskLoader Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyAsyncLoader to Loader<List<MyObject>>

Tags: java, android

I created an AsyncTaskLoader:

```
public class MyAsyncLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<List<MyObject>> {

private MyDataSource myDb_source;   

public MyAsyncLoader(Context context) {
    super(context);
    myDb_source = new MyDataSource(context);
    myDb_source.open();
}

@Override
public List<MyObject> loadInBackground() {
    List<MyObject> my_records = myDb_source.getAllRecords();
    return myObject_records;
}

@Override
public void deliverResult(List<MyObject> data) {
    if(isStarted()){
    super.deliverResult(data);
    }
}

}
```

In my Activity class I have something like this:

public class InActivity extends Activity implements LoaderCallbacks>{

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_in);
    .
    .
    .
    .


        @Override
public Loader<List<MyObject>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    MyAsyncLoader myAsyncLoader = new MyAsyncLoader(this);
    return myAsyncLoader;   // Here i get the ERROR: Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyAsyncLoader to Loader<List<MyObject>>
}
```

return myAsyncLoader;   // Here i get the ERROR: Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyAsyncLoader to Loader>

How can i make this work? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what you imported android.support.v4.content.Loader, not the some other thing.